# Error handling with try/catch or eval while opening file in perl

Tags: perl, eval, perl-module, cpan

I have written simple code snippets, to handle an error occurring while opening the file in restricted(where we need root permission) 
following code works fine and gives an error as o/p

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

my $file_name = "/var/log/test.txt"; # needs root permission to create file

if(open(HAN, ">$file_name")){
    print "sucuessfully opened file \n ";
} else {
    print "Error with if/else while openning file : $! \n";
}
```

o/p:

Error with if/else while opening file : Permission denied

when i use try/catch or eval with same code and opens file

```
try {
    open(HAN, ">$file_name");
} catch {
    print "Error with try/catch while opening file : $_ \n";
};
```

or

```
eval {
    open(HAN, ">$file_name");
};
print " Error with eval while opening file : $@ \n";
```

it shows no output in $_ or $@, why this is happing?

Comment: always put `use warnings`

Comment: usaully known syntax is using open() or die "$!";

Comment: @run-thanks,i know we can use "$!" for open(),but was trying to explore way to do it with try..catch or eval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) does not throw an exception if it fails, it returns a false value and the error is stored in `$!`. Typical usage is therefore

```
open my $fh, '>', $filename or die "Couldn't open '$filename' for writing: $!";
```

If you have a lot of I/O code, or other things that might throw exceptions, you might prefer than `open` (and other I/O functions) *automatically* throw an error on failure. You can do this with [autodie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie):

```
use autodie qw(:io);
```

As @sputnick mentions, you should `use warnings;` in addition to `use strict;`

Finally, here is an example of catching a I/O exception only:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie qw(:io);
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    open my $fh, '>', $filename;
    ... more code ...
}
catch {
    if ($_->isa('autodie::exception') && $_->matches(':io')) {
         print "Error doing something with '$filename': $_\n";
    }
    else {
         die $_;  # rethrow
    }
};
```

On Perl 5.10+, you can use `given` and `when` instead of this verbose code; see the [autodie docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie) for more information.

Comment: @rjh-Thanks for detail explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between an operation failing and an error.

When you try to open a non-existent file (or whatever) the `open` function does not succeed in opening the file. But that doesn't mean there was an error in `open`.  `open` behaved exactly as it was intended to: return a false value when the file couldn't be opened.

`eval BLOCK` and `try...catch` are for catching *errors*—cases when the code was not able to perform as intended.

The failure to open a file may be an error with respect to *your code*—your code may not be able to perform as intended if you can't open a certain file.  In which case, you can handle this and output an error.